# Thymeleaf get current locale

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, locale, thymeleaf

How can I get current locale in thymeleaf template? Thymeleaf context is locale aware, so it would be weird to inject locale on every request, is there some variable I can request in a template?

```
<div th:text="${currentLocale}"></div>
```

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Use the #locale expression:

```
<div th:text="${#locale}"></div>
```

Comment: But when set a unknown language it not show the default current lang, by example `?lang=xx`, `#locale` is `xx` and not the real current lang by default.