Get the Locale in the Thymeleaf template
I want to get the locale in the template. I have tried this:
<select th:id="language-picker-select" name="language-picker-select">
    <option th:value="es" th:selected="${LocaleContextHolder.getLocale()=='es'}">Español</option>
    <option th:value="fr" th:selected="${LocaleContextHolder.getLocale()=='fr'}">Français</option>
    <option th:value="pt" th:selected="${LocaleContextHolder.getLocale()=='pt'}">Português</option>
    <option th:value="en" th:selected="${LocaleContextHolder.getLocale()=='pt'}">English</option>
</select>

but I have this problem:
Caused by: org.attoparser.ParseException: Exception evaluating SpringEL expression: "LocaleContextHolder.getLocale()=='es'" (template: "blogs" - line 89, col 43)
    at org.attoparser.MarkupParser.parseDocument(MarkupParser.java:393)
    at org.attoparser.MarkupParser.parse(MarkupParser.java:257)
    at org.thymeleaf.templateparser.markup.AbstractMarkupTemplateParser.parse(AbstractMarkupTemplateParser.java:230)
    ... 101 more
Caused by: org.thymeleaf.exceptions.TemplateProcessingException: Exception evaluating SpringEL expression: "LocaleContextHolder.getLocale()=='es'" (template: "blogs" - line 89, col 43)
    at org.thymeleaf.spring6.expression.SPELVariableExpressionEvaluator.evaluate(SPELVariableExpressionEvaluator.java:292)
    at org.thymeleaf.standard.expression.VariableExpression.executeVariableExpression(VariableExpression.java:166)
    at org.thymeleaf.standard.expression.SimpleExpression.executeSimple(SimpleExpression.java:66)
    at org.thymeleaf.standard.expression.Expression.execute(Expression.java:109)
    at org.thymeleaf.standard.expression.Expression.execute(Expression.java:138)
    at org.thymeleaf.standard.processor.AbstractStandardExpressionAttributeTagProcessor.doProcess(AbstractStandardExpressionAttributeTagProcessor.java:144)
    at org.thymeleaf.processor.element.AbstractAttributeTagProcessor.doProcess(AbstractAttributeTagProcessor.java:74)
    at org.thymeleaf.processor.element.AbstractElementTagProcessor.process(AbstractElementTagProcessor.java:95)
    at org.thymeleaf.util.ProcessorConfigurationUtils$ElementTagProcessorWrapper.process(ProcessorConfigurationUtils.java:633)
    at org.thymeleaf.engine.ProcessorTemplateHandler.handleOpenElement(ProcessorTemplateHandler.java:1314)
    at org.thymeleaf.engine.TemplateHandlerAdapterMarkupHandler.handleOpenElementEnd(TemplateHandlerAdapterMarkupHandler.java:304)
    at org.thymeleaf.templateparser.markup.InlinedOutputExpressionMarkupHandler$InlineMarkupAdapterPreProcessorHandler.handleOpenElementEnd(InlinedOutputExpressionMarkupHandler.java:278)
    at org.thymeleaf.standard.inline.OutputExpressionInlinePreProcessorHandler.handleOpenElementEnd(OutputExpressionInlinePreProcessorHandler.java:186)
    at org.thymeleaf.templateparser.markup.InlinedOutputExpressionMarkupHandler.handleOpenElementEnd(InlinedOutputExpressionMarkupHandler.java:124)
    at org.attoparser.HtmlElement.handleOpenElementEnd(HtmlElement.java:109)
    at org.attoparser.HtmlMarkupHandler.handleOpenElementEnd(HtmlMarkupHandler.java:297)
    at org.attoparser.MarkupEventProcessorHandler.handleOpenElementEnd(MarkupEventProcessorHandler.java:402)
    at org.attoparser.ParsingElementMarkupUtil.parseOpenElement(ParsingElementMarkupUtil.java:159)
    at org.attoparser.MarkupParser.parseBuffer(MarkupParser.java:710)
    at org.attoparser.MarkupParser.parseDocument(MarkupParser.java:301)
    ... 103 more


Without any knowledge about Thymeleaf, maybe you need to specify the fully-qualified name of LocaleContextHolder (i.e. org.springframework.context.i18n.LocaleContextHolder)?

Exception evaluating SpringEL expression: "org.springframework.context.i18n.LocaleContextHolder.getLocale()=='es'" (template: "blogs" - line 89, col 43)

OK, then I guessed wrong, sorry.

Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40833933/thymeleaf-get-current-locale -- why does #locale not work for your purposes?
